# X-axis date label wrong

Tags: date, highcharts, label

we are binding data to chart date rage from 30/10/2018 to 30/01/2019, but the first labels on the x-axis are showing as 29/10/2018.

can anyone let us know what are the settings to change?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Have you checked time settings: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/time.useUTC?